# Getting the ContentRootPath or getting IHostingEnvironment in a xunit context for .NET core

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I'm creating xunit tests for .NET core (net46 framework) and I'm having a problem getting the root path of the application, so I can locate things such as appsettings.json.

Can someone please explain how I can achieve one of the following:

- Get an instance of IHostingEnvironment
- Retrieve the absolute path of the .NET project containing the xunit test, so I can implement IHostingEnvironment myself.

It might be a very simple problem, I just can't seem to find a good solution.

Comment: Your test project should have its own version of appsettings.json. If you are using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer you can have a line such as var _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>()) which will run the start up in your main project but using elements located in the test project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I remember injecting IHostingEnvironment in an XUnit test is not possible.

This is not ideal, but you could do something like this (ex: SetBasePath):

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("remoteDeploymentConfig.json")
        .AddUserSecrets()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
```

This solution works because if you were to do `dotnet test` you need to do it from within the project directory itself as the `test` here corresponds to the xunit package of that project.

Comment: It worked so it seems Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() is a good choice for my scenarios. .

Comment: Seems this not working for .net core 2.0-preview1 when running test cases with resharper testrunner.